# How to make my logo spin showing the front side on both sides?

Tags: animation

[image]I have got most of the steps complete but I need help with a few. I made an svg of our haunts mummy logo so the when it rotates it will be 3D. I cant figure out how to put the mummy png onto the svg object and have it rotate showing what is on the front on the backside as well. The image shown is the svg of the mummy. All i want to do is add the actual mummy logo onto this and have it rotating showing this side when it rotates to the back as well.

Comment: Could you show some pictures?

Comment: you want to spin with png image or you want to insert image on the svg not clear

Comment: It depends a lot on your object, and how you want to do this... your imported svg could become a flat object with a single face whiich,  if textured with an image, will show it on both sides... for an example try importing the image with "images as planes" bundled addon...

Comment: Scaling one axis from one to zero and back will also give the appearance of rotation.

Answer (score 2):

it seems you want to show *the same* image on front and back (we don't know if as in a coin, ie the same exact image on both sides, or as a photographic film, ie the backside looks reversed ).

This is also a multiple question, as different steps are needed. So I will just drive you through what you need to learn to do.

Since you import a svg you get a curve object: it must be converted to mesh object first (alt+c), then add a face. If it needs depth, you can extrude that face (and so you get two faces, one on each side).

then you must assign the image to the face(s). This can be done in a number of ways (uvmap, different materials...) and it also can depend on the rendering engine used...

Lastly you need the rotation. This is done adding a few (rotation) keyframes at different frames, enough for one full turn. by default you get an "eased" movement (starts and stops slowly) but you can later edit animation curves to make it constantly rotating, without "easing", if you wish so...

As you see, you have different (simple) tasks to learn. As there are already many answers for these tasks, look for them with the search tool...

edit: I noticed you added an example image but it seems not symmetrical, so it won't be possible to show the exact image on both sides, apparently. To explain better, I created an example with a (even more) asymmetrical mummy image and imported svg curve, like this:

[image: yummy mummy]

here

1. the svg has been converted (<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) to mesh, and rotated 90°over X
2. then selecting all vertices I created a face (<kbd>F</kbd>).
3. then I extruded it over Y (<kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>) a bit to give it depth.
4. then in edit mode, ortho mode, I created a UVmap (<kbd>U</kbd> project from view, bounds) for the face
5. then I created a simple material, shadeless.
6. added a texture (the mummy .png) and used the UV mapping method, specifying the UVmap created at point 4. This makes the .png fit perfectly the object face.
7. lastly I animated a full turnaround with using keyframes, then gave linear extrapolation.

If you wish to learn, try asking here about each of the above points that you don't understand (maybe try before because it could be really simple) just by referring to manual or other examples

Comment: Thank you this will help although how do i add the faces. Also i dont want the backside to look reversed i want it to show the front on both sides.

Comment: Is it possible that you could email me and walk me through this step by step I am still new to blender and 3D. I know how to keyframe and such byt this part is just beating me.

Comment: sorry but assistance by mail is not possible and even a full tutorial here is offtopic.There's a help page suggesting resources for beginners here https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/beginners-reference. Try stuff linked there. Btw, you add a face selecting vertices and pressing "F".

Comment: Since it seems you are an absolute beginner, I suggest you to follow some basic tutorial on the web and/or searching this site for answers to basic questions, like "how do I add a face?", or - if you don't find similar issues (I doubt) - post your own questions, but keep one question for one topic (so, post multiple questions if needed).

Comment: I just edited the answer, to add an animation sample of what you could easily do.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question you want to spin 2 different png images.

Add a circle or any shape with 2 faces.

Add 1 image at front and other image at back with 2 different material applied to it.

With the circle selected Add animation to it.

**Animation**

With the circle selected add 1st key frame with rotation Pressing "I" key Rotation of 90 Repeat the process adding the key frame untill it make a complete rotation.

Maybe this is the final result with 2 images spinning

[image]