# Texturing Scalable Vector Graphics

Tags: texturing, svg

I am trying to make an extruded version of this image of Gary Smith,

[image]

so I used GIMP to cut him out of the picture and exported the path as an SVG file, and imported it to blender and set it as 2D. But when I try to texture it, I get a completely black model.

[image]

How do I texture it?

Edit Mode:

[image]

Comment: Have you UV Unwrapped it?

Comment: @AshutoshBudhdeo  I tried selecting all the vertices and pressing U, but nothing happened. I'll edit my question to contain a screenshot of edit mode

Comment: Can you see the Unwrapped model in the UV Editor?

Comment: @AshutoshBudhdeo I cannot

Comment: @AshutoshBudhdeo Alright, I added a photo of edit mode to the post.

Comment: Go to edit mode, switch to top view by pressing 7, select everything by pressing A and press U and select project from view. After this, you should be able to see your model in the UV image editor.

Comment: @AshutoshBudhdeo When I press U, nothing happens

Comment: I saw your edit mode screenshot and it looks like the model is only made up of unconnected vertices. A 3D model should have it's vertices connected to each other to form faces so that textures can be applied to those faces. Also, the topology of the model is not good at all. If you want to make a 3D model of gary smith, I would suggest you to model it manually. If you want a 2D flat plane, i would suggest you to alpha mask the image in Photoshop or Gimp and Import it in blender with the help of Images As Planes add-on

Comment: @AshutoshBudhdeo The Images as Planes add on idea worked out, thank you for your time.

Comment: Edit: I misunderstood what you were doing with the path. I think the step you were missing was to convert the path to a mesh before UV unwrapping. I don't know my way around curve objects very well, but you should be able to texture a mesh object as expected. Alt+c (I think) for convert curve to mesh and vice versa.

Comment: see if this helps https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92317/how-to-make-my-logo-spin-showing-the-front-side-on-both-sides/92331#92331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood the question here are steps follow it

1. Import the SVG file
2. Convert the curve to mesh by press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and select curve from Mesh
3. Go to edit mode Press <kbd>U</kbd> and select Project from view (Bounds)
4. Make a new window as node editor and connect the image.
5. Assign the material to the mesh.